# g77: unrecognized option `-trapuv' f771: error: invalid option `ips2'

Tags: fortran, gfortran, g77

I am using g77 (gcc 3.4.6) in my fedora 20. I got compiler errors:

> g77: unrecognized option `-trapuv'
>
> f771: error: invalid option `ips2'

How can I solve this problem?

Also, if I want to use gfortran instead, what are the equivalent options?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the result of `g77 --version`? It's possible `g77` is calling `gfortran` with legacy options anyways.

Comment: g77 --version gives:                                                                                     GNU Fortran (GCC) 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-29.fc19)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: Why are you using an ancient compiler?

Comment: -trapuv is a flag to f2c, a "compiler" of even more ancient vintage than g77, no idea what the error is though. Moving to a modern Fortran compiler is almost certainly the way to go, could you show us your full compile and link lines, then somebody will probably be able to help you with the gfortran equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. It is a already written code by somebody else and it comes with makefile using g77. Here are the compiling flags that is used:  FFLAGS = -C  -trapuv  -mips2  -c. I am also looking for the gfrotran equivalent of these flags.

Comment: Well those are debugging flags - you do realise that if you use them the code will run at far from full speed? Anyway a rough equivalent for gfortran is -fcheck=all -finit-real=snan -c . You should also show us the linker flags, you might need to make changes there.

Comment: Ian, Thanks a lot. It compiles by using the flags you provided but a lot of errors like: Warning: Deleted feature: ASSIGN statement at (1) and Warning: Deleted feature: Assigned GOTO statement at (1). The linkage flag is gfortran -o a.out $(OBJECTS) /usr/local/lib/2003/lib/libkernlib.a

Comment: Try -std=legacy for the assigned goto warnings

Comment: Works, thanks a lot.